# OpenCV reading image pixel value

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing, visual-studio-2013

I'm trying very simple thing with opencv but getting error. 
I'm just trying read 16bit png image and access to the specific pixel value. I tried many ways but couldn't manage the get value. I'm using OpenCV3.0 on windows8 64bit.

NOTE: while reading image using CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE is fine, but CV_LOAD_IMAGE_ANYDEPTH rising error. But when i use CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE my highest pixel is 9, which should be around 2000

I uploaded example image.[example image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0FD0X.png)

my example code:

```
#include "opencv2/core/core.hpp"
#include "opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp"
#include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
cv::Mat frame = cv::imread("filepath", CV_LOAD_IMAGE_ANYDEPTH );//using CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE is fine, but CV_LOAD_IMAGE_ANYDEPTH rising error
frame.convertTo(frame, CV_16U);// to be sure... i omitted this part also and same error
double min, max;
cv::Point mloc, mxloc;
cv::minMaxLoc(frame, &min, &max, &mloc, &mxloc);
//i can access min and max values but not the specific pixel value
float zmx = frame.at<unsigned char>(118, 38);//rise error
float zm = frame.at<float>(30,40);//rise error
return 0;
```

}

Error message:

Unhandled exception at 0x00007FF8EB288A5C in OpenCVTest.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: cv::Exception at memory location 0x000000A47F40F230.

But i think this is misleading error, i check the my image is 320*240, so i'm sure that there is pixel at that location.

I tried with Scalar also, but i'm getting same error

Comment: you are defining `frame` twice?

Comment: post the error message please. there are countless errors in this world

Comment: @Thsane it is just mistake while i'm coppying my code., error is same

Comment: 16 bit is type "short" typically. maybe unsigned for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of things you should notice.
First you are defining `frame` twice.

second, this line `float zmx = frame.at<unsigned char>(118, 38);` has a couple of issues. you are assigning `unsigned char` to a `float`. also you should notice the order is reversed to access the `x,y` pixel value you call `frame.at<unsigned char>(y, x)` then best way to assign to a `Scalar` instead like this

```
Scalar fmx = frame.at<uchar>(118, 38);
```

or use `Point` to avoid confusion

```
Scalar fmx = frame.at<uchar>(Point(38,118));
```

last thing, make sure you loaded the image properly and that `frame` has the image data

---

UPDATE

I just tested your code and it worked fine (check below), I can't think of anything but not finding the image in the path provided

```
#include "opencv2/core/core.hpp"
#include "opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp"
#include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    cv::Mat frame = cv::imread("0FD0X.png", CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE);
    frame.convertTo(frame, CV_16U);// to be sure... i omitted this part also and same error
    double min, max;
    cv::Point mloc, mxloc;
    cv::minMaxLoc(frame, &min, &max, &mloc, &mxloc);
    //i can access min and max values but not the specific pixel value
    float zmx = frame.at<unsigned char>(118, 38);// no error
    float zm = frame.at<float>(30, 40);// no error
    std::cout << zmx << std::endl;  // out 0
    std::cout << min << std::endl; // out 0
    std::cout << max << std::endl;  // out 9
    std::cout << mloc << std::endl; // out [0,0]
    std::cout << mxloc << std::endl; // out [125,30]
    return 0;
}
```

---

**Update #2** to access multichannel image you need to access using the `Vec3b` data type. Also notice the order of the point coordinates. check the following code

```
#include "opencv2/core/core.hpp"
#include "opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp"
#include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    cv::Mat frame = cv::imread("0FD0X.png", CV_LOAD_IMAGE_ANYDEPTH);
    frame.convertTo(frame, CV_16U);// to be sure... i omitted this part also and same error
    double min, max;
    cv::Point mloc, mxloc;
    cv::minMaxLoc(frame, &min, &max, &mloc, &mxloc);
    //i can access min and max values but not the specific pixel value
ushort pValShort = frame.at<ushort>(38, 118);// no error 
Vec3b pValVec = frame.at<Vec3b>(38, 118);// no error 
Vec3b pValVecPoint = frame.at<Vec3b>(Point(118,38));// no error 
std::cout << pValShort << std::endl; // out 2423
std::cout << pValVec << std::endl; // out [166,8,165]
std::cout << pValVecPoint << std::endl; // out [166,8,165]

    std::cout << min << std::endl; // out 0
    std::cout << max << std::endl;  // out 2423
    std::cout << mloc << std::endl; // out [0,0]
    std::cout << mxloc << std::endl; // out [118,38]
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: As i commented below line also rising error, i tried with Scalar also error is same, even without any assignment i'm getting same error

Comment: are you sure the image is loaded into the frame?? check the frame size after loading `int rows = frame.rows;
int cols = frame.cols;`. maybe wrong path

Comment: Yes, i printed rows and cols and i can see this values at debug

Comment: why do you convert the image to cv16u if you want to read float values?

Comment: Can you try with CV_LOAD_IMAGE_ANYDEPTH since, this is giving error. I figure out now

Comment: `std::cout << max << std::endl;  // out 2423` and 
`std::cout << mxloc << std::endl; // out [118,38]` with CV_LOAD_IMAGE_ANYDEPTH

Comment: i can reach min and max values but not a specific location.

Comment: @Thesane, why i'm getting a 3 values it is just a single channel depth image. as you see max value should be 2423, but when you reach with the points it is different

Comment: you can still access the single value using `ushort pValShort = frame.at<ushort>(38, 118);`, the 3 values represent the BGR values of the pixel

Answer (score 3):

Your biggest problem is that you're trying to access a 16 bpp image, i.e. a `Mat` of type `CV_16U` with the wrong data type. You should use `frame.at<ushort>(...)` in case of single channel 16 bpp image (I suppose this is the case here), or with `frame.at<Vec3w>(...)` for 3 channels images.

Also you should make sure that you're loading the image properly. Using `imread` with parameter `IMREAD_GRAYSCALE` you're converting your image to 8bpp, which is not what you want. You should use `IMREAD_ANYDEPTH` or `IMREAD_UNCHANGED`.

Take a look at this code:

```
#include<opencv2/opencv.hpp>

int main()
{
    // Read the image as original bpp
    cv::Mat frame = cv::imread("path_to_image", cv::IMREAD_ANYDEPTH);

    // Be sure that the image is loaded
    if (frame.empty())
    {
        // No image loaded
        return -1;
    }

    // Be sure that the image is 16bpp and single channel
    if (frame.type() != CV_16U || frame.channels() != 1)
    {
        // Wrong image depth or channels
        return -1;
    }


    double min_val, max_val;
    cv::Point min_loc, max_loc;
    cv::minMaxLoc(frame, &min_val, &max_val, &min_loc, &max_loc);

    // Access values with correct data type
    ushort zmx = frame.at<ushort>(max_loc);

    return 0;
}
```